# Calculating the Area Between Curves

Tags: integration

Consider the area between the graphs determined by ${x+4y = 12}$ and ${x+9 = y^2}$. Solve this as a sum of integrals.

$$\int_a^b {f(x)dx} + \int_b^c {g(x)dx} $$
I am having difficulty trying to find f(x) and g(x) as well as the a, b, and c. My initial attempts involved solving for y and determining where there was an intersection but my answer is incorrect. Is there a theorem that I am missing? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to view this sort of problem?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Where did you determine was an intersection?

Comment: Given that what? There is no information given, only an expression.

Comment: I determined an intersection at (0,3).

Comment: There's another intersection too

Answer (score 1):

There are two points of intersection:  $(0,3)$ and $(40,-7)$.

We can write the area as a double integral:

$$I= \int_{-7}^3 \int_{y^2-9}^{12-4y} \,dx\,dy$$

Doing the inner integral first, will give

$$I=\int_{-7}^3 (12-4y) \, dy - \int_{-7}^3 (y^2 - 9) \, dy$$ which is the form you want.

The result is $$I=500/3.$$

Comment: I think you mean $dxdy$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to correct the $dx$s in the second part (they should be $dy$s)

Comment: Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture of your region.

The first curve is a line.
The second curve is a parabola.  However it is sideways to the standard orientation.
[image]

Now, I would be inclined to integrate this with respect to y and say

$A = \int_a^b 12-4y-(y^2-9) \ dy$

And the limits of the integration would be where

$y^2 + 4y - 21 = 0$

$A = \int_{-7}^3 12-4y-y^2 \ dy$

But that is not what you have been asked for.

Instead they want
$A = \int_0^a 2\sqrt {x-9}  \ dx + \int_a^b 3-\frac 14 x +\sqrt {x-9}  \ dx$

As for $a,b$

We have found the y coordinate for each of these points of intersection.  It should be too hard to solve for the x coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Given $x+4y = 12,$ $y=3-\dfrac x4$.

Given $x+9 = y^2$, $y=\pm\sqrt{x+9}$ when $x\ge-9$

(and otherwise there is no real $y$ satisfying $x+9 = y^2).$

The two points of intersection are $(0,3)$ and $(40,-7)$,

since  $x+9=\left(3-\dfrac x 4\right)^2 \iff x\left(\dfrac x {16}-\dfrac52\right)=0\iff x=0 $ or $40.$

For $x\in [-9,0],$ $\sqrt{x+9}\le3-\dfrac x4,$ so the area is $\int_{-9}^0 \left(\sqrt {x+9}-\left(-\sqrt{x+9}\right)\right) dx .$

For $x\in [0,40],$ $\sqrt{x+9}\ge3-\dfrac x4,$ so the area is $\int_{0}^{40} \left(3-\dfrac x4-\left(-\sqrt{x+9}\right)\right) dx.$

The total area is therefore $$\int_{-9}^0 2\sqrt {x+9}  \ dx + \int_0^{40} \left(3-\frac 14 x +\sqrt {x+9} \right)  dx $$
$$= 2\times\dfrac23(x+9)^{3/2}\bigg|_{-9}^0+\left(3x-\dfrac18x^2+\dfrac23(x+9)^{3/2}\right)\bigg|_0^{40}$$
$$=36+(120-200+\dfrac23 7^3)-\dfrac233^3=36+\dfrac{392}3=\dfrac{500} 3.$$